# How to deploy talend esb route on talend karaf?

Tags: talend, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have created route in Talend Open Studio for ESB. Inside the route I start cxf service. Everything works great when route is running inside studio but I need to deploy it on ESB runtime.
I've exported *.kar file to `~/Runtime_ESBSE/container/deploy` folder, and in Karaf console, after executing `osgi:list` command I can see my route:

```
[ 244] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   80] tmp (0.1)
```

I don't have any errors in console logs so I assume that route is installed correctly but my service isn't started (or the whole route isn't started at all). I cannot get access to service which should be created from route. 
After executing `start 244` (244 is an id of the route) nothing happens but when I execute `stop 244` route status changes from `Active` to `Resolved` (and after `start` it changes back to Active).
Does anyone know how to make it works? What should I do to force that route to behave just like inside open studio?
Thanks from advance.
EDIT:
I've checked features as well and it looks like everything is ok. `tmp-feature` is installed so I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: When we deploy JAR files we basically copy them to the deploy folder, overwrite the previous version, then karaf picks it up automatically. I don't remember when I've opened karaf. Last time it went fine for more than 6 months, then needed a restart, it is really stable.

Comment: I did the same. Just copied *.kar file to deploy folder, and in logs I could see that karaf deployed route. it looks like everything is fine, feature is installed, bundle is installed but route isn't working ;/

Comment: Try increasing the log level? Typically we find errors in either karaf-wrapper.log (we use a service to start the karaf wrapper) or tesb.log.
I would also recommend to try deploying routes with more simple endpoints like file based endpoints to verify that your deployment process works. This could identify potential problems with cxf.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at container/log/tesb.log and see what happens when you start your route.
Also take care of the service url you set (http://0.0.0.0 ? other)